# Sql query without using loops

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one database table test.The structure of the table is:

```
Col1(varchar)  Col2(number)
```

The table has 2 rows:

```
Abc 5
Def 6
```

I desire the output to be:

```
Col1
Abc
Abc
Abc
Abc
Abc
Def
Def
Def
Def
Def
Def
```

I need to write a single query without using plsql loops to acheive this output.Please help.

Comment: Can't you just use `SELECT col1, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, ABC, def, def, def, def, def`?

Comment: Is it correct that you do not want to use `plsql` because you want the query to work with more than just Postgresql/Oracle?

Comment: Which RDBMS? Please tag accordingly. (This can be done with some variation on a `nums` table, but even that varies across systems.)

Comment: Join on a numbers table.

Comment: I actually work in Tableau reporting tool.we use Oracle 11g darabase.Tableau dont support Plsql.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select     col1
from       mytable,
           (select     rownum r
            from       dual
            connect by rownum <= (select max(col2) from mytable))
where      r <= col2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1, col2 ) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query - Using a Collection**:

```
SELECT t.Col1
FROM   table_name t,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT 1
             FROM   DUAL
             WHERE t.Col2 > 0
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.Col2
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       );
```

**Query - Using a recursive sub-query factoring clause**:

```
WITH sqfc ( COL1, COL2 ) AS (
  SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2 - 1 FROM sqfc WHERE col2 > 1
)
SELECT col1
FROM   sqfc
WHERE  col2 > 0 -- Needed if col2 is zero
ORDER BY Col1;
```

**Output (from both queries)**:

```
COL1
----
ABC  
ABC  
ABC  
ABC  
ABC  
DEF  
DEF  
DEF  
DEF  
DEF  
DEF
```